# Pandas replace the value of a column based on the value of the same column in another row

Tags: pandas, dataframe, multiple-conditions

I am trying to replace the values of a dataframe column with the value of the same column but from another row.

The ID of the COUNTRY with type "TO_REPLACE" must be replaced by the ID of the same COUNTRY with type "ORIGINAL".

Example DF:

```
ID     NAME        TYPE
---
ID1    COUNTRY1    ORIGINAL       <-- ORIGINAL of COUNTRY1 (ID1)
ID2    COUNTRY1    TO_REPLACE1    <-- ID must be ID1
ID3    COUNTRY1    TO_REPLACE2    <-- ID must be ID1
...
ID4    COUNTRYX    TO_REPLACE1    <-- ID must be ID6
ID5    COUNTRYX    TO_REPLACE2    <-- ID must be ID6
ID6    COUNTRYX    ORIGINAL       <-- ORIGINAL of COUNTRYX (ID6)
```

I need:
if -TYPE- is "TO_REPLACE1" or "TO_REPLACE2" then find that -NAME- with -TYPE- "ORIGINAL" and put the "ORIGINAL ID" on ID.
At the end in this example all -NAME- COUNTRY1 must be ID1 (the "ORIGINAL" ID) and COUNTRYX must be ID6.

Result:

```
ID     NAME        TYPE
---
ID1    COUNTRY1    ORIGINAL
ID1    COUNTRY1    TO_REPLACE1    <-- ID replaced
ID1    COUNTRY1    TO_REPLACE2    <-- ID replaced
...
ID6    COUNTRYX    TO_REPLACE1    <-- ID replaced
ID6    COUNTRYX    TO_REPLACE2    <-- ID replaced
ID6    COUNTRYX    ORIGINAL
```

After many attempts, the closest is this one:

```
df.loc[(df['TYPE'].isin(['TO_REPLACE1', 'TO_REPLACE2']), 'ID'] = df.loc[df['TYPE'] == 'ORIGINAL', 'ID'].values[0]
```

But replace only by the first "ORIGINAL ID" found.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [`mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html)/[`where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and use a [`groupby.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df['ID'] = (df['ID']
 .where(df['TYPE'].eq('ORIGINAL'))
 .groupby(df['NAME']).transform('first')
)
```

Or with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['ID'] = df['NAME'].map(df[df['TYPE'].eq('ORIGINAL')].set_index('NAME')['ID'])
```

A more generic approach if you really need to match "ORIGINAL" and "TO_REPLACE" (assuming other values):

```
df['ID'] = (df['ID']
 .mask(df['TYPE'].str.startswith('TO_REPLACE'))
 .fillna(df['NAME'].map(df[df['TYPE'].eq('ORIGINAL')]
                        .set_index('NAME')['ID']))
)
```

Output:

```
    ID      NAME         TYPE
0  ID1  COUNTRY1     ORIGINAL
1  ID1  COUNTRY1  TO_REPLACE1
2  ID1  COUNTRY1  TO_REPLACE2
3  ID6  COUNTRYX  TO_REPLACE1
4  ID6  COUNTRYX  TO_REPLACE2
5  ID6  COUNTRYX     ORIGINAL
```

Answer (score 0):

The code snippet below creates a `new_ID` column with the replaced IDs.

Output:

[image]

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ID': [f'ID{i}' for i in range(1, 7)],
     'NAME': ['COUNTRY1'] * 3 + ['COUNTRY2'] * 3,
     'TYPE': ['ORIGINAL', 'TO_REPLACE1', 'TO_REPLACE2',
              'TO_REPLACE1', 'TO_REPLACE2', 'ORIGINAL']
     }
)

ids_reference = df.loc[df.TYPE=='ORIGINAL']

df['new_ID'] = df.apply(
    lambda x: ids_reference.loc[ids_reference.NAME==x.NAME, 'ID'].item(),
    axis=1
)
```